# Angular, how to set focus in a specific FormControl of FormArray

Tags: angular

lHow ca I set focus to a specific field in a formArray?

this is the formArray:

```
    this.productForm = this.formBuilder.array([
     this.formBuilder.group({
     code: [null],
     description: [null],
     unitPrice: [null],
     qty: [null],
     discount: [null],
     vat: [null],
     total: [null],
     amount: [null],
     taxAmount: [null]
  })
]);
```

I can have a lot of this formGroup and I need to focus a specific description field.
Is there a smart way in angular?

Comment: The FormBuilder API does not say anything: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder

Answer (score 3):

If you know the specific item you want to focus it would be fairly straightforward first of all by adding a template reference:

```
<input
  #fieldName
  type="text"
  id="fieldName"
  name="fieldName"
  formControlName="yourFieldName" />
```

Then in your component (probably in ngAfterViewInit() method):

```
@ViewChild('fieldName') fieldName: ElementRef;
```

Then to focus on your element:

```
this.fieldName.nativeElement.focus();
```

NB this will be vulnerable to XSS attacks though

Comment: ok but in my case the reference is multiple because is an element of a formArray, so I can't refer to a specific element

Comment: If you know which element you want, and you control the template itself, you can craft it so it writes an id/name in the way you want, which you can access via the component.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use angular2-focus package in your application for consistent use from below location. You will be able to reuse the code anywhere in your application.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-focus

Using this package, you will be able to focus any input element as below.

```
<input type="text" focus="true">
```

Include module as below

```
import {NgModule, Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FocusModule} from 'angular2-focus';
@NgModule({
  imports: [FocusModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue.  I resolved it by rethinking the implementation.

My situation was that I wanted to focus on the row (first input) when the use tabbed (blurred) out of the last row.  I had implemented a *directive* to handle the blur and focus on my Row.

```js
import { Directive, Input, Output, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[focusedRow]'
})
export class RowDirective {
  static tabindex = 1;
  static currentFocus = null;

  private timer: any = null;

  @HostBinding('tabindex') public tabIndex: number = 0;

  @Input('formGroupName') public rowNumber: number;

  @Output('focus') public onFocus: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
  @Output('blur')  public onBlur: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor(private elm: ElementRef) {
    this.tabIndex = RowDirective.tabindex++;
  }

  @HostListener('focusin', ['$event'])
  public focusHandler(event: Event) {
    // When we're not the current focus.
    if (RowDirective.currentFocus !== this) {
      this.onFocus.emit(event);

      RowDirective.currentFocus = this;

    } else {
      // Stop our blur from happening since it's the same row
      if (this.timer) {
        window.clearTimeout(this.timer);
        this.timer = null;
      }
    }
  }
  @HostListener('focusout', ['$event'])
  public blurHandler(event: Event) {
    this.timer = window.setTimeout(() => {
      // If our row has changed, then we have blurred.
      this.onBlur.emit(event);

      // Clear if this is still listed as the Focused Row.
      if (RowDirective.currentFocus === this) {
        RowDirective.currentFocus = null;
      }
    }, 200);
  }
}
```

What I did was, instead of trying to battle the Angular Form Group, I simply made it that when a new Row was created from my Reactive Form and the row was added, because the form row element had the *directive* applied, the better solution was to simply focus the row (first input) when the *directive* initialised.

This was done using the `OnInit` interface.  So the above code was adjusted to include the interface (changes below);

```js
import { Directive, Input, Output, OnInit, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[focusedRow]'
})
export class RowDirective implements OnInit {
  ....

  ngOnInit() {
    // Focus on the first Form Element
    this.elm.nativeElement.querySelector('input').focus();
  }

  ....
}
```

So create the above Directive, and then add that directive to your Form Array element...

```js
 <tr *ngFor="let entry of myForms.controls; let index=index" [formGroupName]="index" focusedRow (focus)="rowFocus(index)" (blur)="rowBlur(index)">
```

This way, anytime a row is created, it focuses the first form element.

The beauty of this solution is that it also works when the user clicked my "Add new Row" button, and you get some cool Focus and Blur handlers on your [table] row.  (the secret to that by the way is the use of the `tabindex` attribute)

Hope that helps your situation.